# Convert Unity Settings from binary to text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, settings

Looks like in 2017.2 version Unity changed their Settings format from binary to text. At least, projects, created with Unity 2017.2.0f3, create PlayerSettings, QualitySettings etc. in text format.

Text compared to binary increases commits quality (you can now see a normal diff).

But project, created in Unity 5.6, opened in 2017.2, still shows Settings files in binary.

Is it a fast way to convert settings files to text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know that you used to be able to force text (things might have changed in 2017), which was especially useful for git merge conflicts. According to [this blog](http://www.deadlyfingers.net/gamedev/unity3d/unity-git/), you can enable this by:

> Edit > Project Settings > Editor menu and then under Asset
>   Serialization Mode choose Force Text

This should make assets text only; however, I'm not sure this handles the specific setting files you were looking to convert.

The official unity documentation that covers this is [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/Versioncontrolintegration.html).

Comment: This _will_ effect all the settings in the ProjectSetting directory in question. They are saved as "_.asset_" files regardless of the setting but internally will convert to YAML when forced as text.  It's worth mentioning that this setting is project-wide and will effect your "_.scene", "_.prefab", and other "_.asset" files as well; that blog post should be read carefully to avoid auto-merging errors when using these settings along with source control.  As another note, the "Mixed" option for the Asset Serialization Mode will leave relevant files as-is but the "force" options act immediately.